# IO shield is causing my motherboard to not align with case standoffs

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, io

I have a very quick question regarding the IO shield in my PC build. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to this, so this might be a silly question. I've recently started building a computer but I've hit a bit of an issue that's taken me around in circles.

The case I've got is a Obsidian 500D case and the motherboard I have is a MSI MPG Z490. I've installed the CPU, RAM and SSD on to the board no problem, but I've had an issue with screwing the board into the case itself.

The reason I bought the case was because it supported this motherboard (I used the site pcpartpicker.com to confirm this). When I go to place the motherboard in the case, the screw holes in the board don't fully align with the standoffs on the case. I've try wiggling the board around to try and see if I can align it, but to no avail.

But funnily enough, I removed the IO-shield from the motherboard (It came pre-attached to it) and tried again with aligning the board. And, it aligned perfectly. With no problems at all. My question is, is this normal? Surely it should just fit on without having to go through the need to remove the IO-shield? That's needed, right?

I've also tried taking the IO-shield off, placing it in the case, then attaching the motherboard but it doesn't align (like before). Although, the IO-shield doesn't snap into place when I put it in the case. After looking online most other builds I've seen have the IO-shield snap into place, so perhaps I'm being too gentle? One thing I did note was that the IO-shield seems to be a little too thin, i.e. it could be moved a little bit left and right in the slot (which I assume comes from it not being snapped into place?)

Thank you for the help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

> The case I've got is an Obsidian 500D case and the motherboard I have is an MSI MPG Z490. I've installed the CPU, RAM, and SSD on the board with no problem, but I've had an issue with screwing the board into the case itself.

The case claims it supports MATX, ATX, and ITX.  The motherboard you purchase is an ATX board.

> The reason I bought the case was that it supported this motherboard (I used the site pcpartpicker.com to confirm this). When I go to place the motherboard in the case, the screw holes in the board don't fully align with the standoffs on the case. I've tried wiggling the board around to try and see if I can align it, but to no avail.

You are aware that particular website isn't 100% accurate right?

> But funnily enough, I removed the IO-shield from the motherboard (It came pre-attached to it) and tried again with aligning the board. And, it aligned perfectly. With no problems at all. My question is, is this normal? Surely it should just fit on without having to go through the need to remove the IO-shield? That's needed, right?

It's supposed to be tight.

> I've also tried taking the IO-shield off, placing it in the case, then attaching the motherboard but it doesn't align (like before). Although, the IO-shield doesn't snap into place when I put it in the case. After looking online most other builds I've seen have the IO-shield snap into place, so perhaps I'm being too gentle? One thing I did note was that the IO-shield seems to be a little too thin, i.e. it could be moved a little bit left and right in the slot (which I assume comes from it not being snapped into place?)

It shouldn't be necessary but what you describe seems to be common with this particular case.  Since the I/O shield is typically just snapped into place, the fact the I/O shield is screwed in, it looks like it was intentionally designed to be removed.

Comment: After trying to refit the case, the I/O shield won't snap into place at all. I have noticed there's quite a bit of wiggled room for the I/O shield and the I/O slot (both horizontally and vertically). Would it be acceptable to install the motherboard without the I/O shield attached to the motherboard?

Comment: An update for anyone who happens to have this combination of case / motherboard. I've managed to get the motherboard in the case with the I/O shield still on the motherboard. it turns out to place it in, you kinda need to align it away from the I/O slot. So, it's higher on the I/O slot side than the other side, and it's kinda just clicks in! Although, not all the screw holes aligned. The central support stand fits, alongside the 2 screws on the middle row, and all on the bottom row, and the top left screw. The top middle and top right don't align fully enough to screw (maybe from I/O, idk).